# 1998 World Cup limited edition soccer figure

Tags: minifigures

I bought a limited edition World Cup soccer figure in Paris during the games in 1998, #3005.  It does not have the shell logo on the package -but does say limited edition on the right lower corner. The package also says collect both teams.  Does anyone know anything about this lego figure?

Comment: Do you have a picture by any chance?

Comment: I believe you are referring to a set numbered 3305, not 3005.

Answer (score 3):

Is this the figure in question?

[image]

He's the limited edition English or Scottish team player. The other limited edition figure was a Dutch (Netherlands) player. Lego released an entire soccer theme in 1998 in conjunction with the World Cup, which you can see [here on Brickset](http://brickset.com/sets/theme-Town/subtheme-Football).

Comment: Yes it is thank you so much. I could only find the shell branded wrapper with searching.